# What types of SCSI connectors are these?

Tags: hard-drive, cable, scsi

I was given an old server and old storage array, and told that they go together.
My boss wants me to gain access and migrate all the old data to our current file server.

Knowing basically zilch about scsi, I'm looking for some help in properly identifying these connectors so that I can buy the correct cable.

[image]

Any and all tips/suggestions/side-thoughts would be greatly appreciated =D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [here](http://www.scsi4me.com/scsi-connectors.htm)[image]:

Looks like a (5) High Density DB 50-pin Screw Type and a (6) VHDCI 68-Pin type.

All of these are pretty old.  Best of luck.

Comment: Thanks-a-BUNCH!  ... counting the pins, it looks like a _**#8**_ and a #6. Much appreciated.